# Wordpress homepage would produce gibberish

Tags: wordpress

This would usually be the last place I'd ask for such a trivial question, but has anyone encountered this before?

[image: Image of how the website appears as of now]

Wordpress admin is working all fine, but like provided in the screenshot any page would is gibberish letters.

I have updated wordpress to the latest version, as well as the premium theme I am using. wp-confing file also seems okay. Has this happened to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

That is an image translated into text. When Dreamweaver was the most favored tool, we often saw that when we accidentally tried to open a .jpg or other image file in Dreamweaver, instead of inserting it into an HTML type file.

Comment: I understand your sarcasm, and your mocking towards me is well deserved, I will not deny that. Problem is I have already reinstalled and changed everything that resides within the wordpress folder.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you have read a perfectly honest answer as sarcasm. This is indeed the type of code that we saw in Dreamweaver when we opened an image file, and since Dreamweaver is no longer as popular, we don't see it as much any more. I'm not quite sure how that is sarcasm.

When I tried to go to the site at first, my browser was seeing it as an image. Now, the site is working fine. So, I'm not sure what caused the change.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue before with W3 Total Cache as well. If you have that installed, try disabling it and see if it goes away.

You may need to reinstall the plugin if something has become messed up (particularly after reinstalling WordPress.) I'd recommend exporting your W3 settings first though so you can reinstall and configure easily.

Comment: W3 Total Cache after a WP update was the culprit in my case, thanks!